# How to change MySQL error log file format

Tags: mysql, linux, logging, format

I am running a shared hosting LAMP server.  I have several clients using the same CMS software, which utilizes MySQL as the back-end database.  I am getting a 145 error in my `/var/log/mysqld.log` regarding the `mod_statistics.MYI` file:

> 120713  8:53:22 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't open file:
>   'mod_statistics.MYI' (errno: 145)

I know how to fix the 145 error: that's not the issue.  However, FINDING the correct `mod_statistics.MYI` is the problem for me, since there are a LOT of clients on this server who have their own copies of this table.

My question: 
How can the MySQL logging format be modified to add the full path of this file to the log output?  I really hate to have to go through *each* customer loading this table to see if it's corrupted.

I have Googled and read the MySQL log file documentation, which doesn't discuss changing the file format.

THANK YOU!

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like its possible to format the MySQL error log.

One possible solution to this is to use the MyISAM auto-recovery mode when you start the server: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_myisam-recover. The description makes it sound like it gives more info about the table(s) that it's working on.

It might help to locate the table and it might get it fixed for you.

Comment: Nice! This worked. Specifically I did the following:
1) Edit the /etc/my.cnf file  
2) Under the [mysqld] section, add a line: "myisam-recover=BACKUP"  
3) Restart the mysqld daemon  
  
Now the log file (/var/log/mysqld.log) shows "checking table:" for each table that is loaded, then for the offending table it shows "Recovering table: " and the complete path to the table.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting  
I couldn't get it to add line breaks.